# What is the best practice to read a file (under lib) while developing a gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rubymine

I experienced some pain when deal with the "path" in developing a gem.
Here is the folder structure

production codes:

```
lib/gem_name/foo/templates/some_template.erb
lib/gem_name/foo/bar.rb
```

test codes:

```
test/gem_name/foo/bar_test.rb
```

In bar.rb, I read the template by:

```
File.read("templates/some_template.erb") => Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory
```

when I run the unit test in bar_test.rb in RubyMine, it gives me the error:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - D:/.../test/gem_name/foo/templates/some_template.erb
```

Obviously the **test** in the path is wrong.

My question are,

1. How to deal with this issues?
2. What is the best practice to handle
   such **path** problem while developing a gem?

**Edit**:
Since `__FILE__` only returns the path of the file it is written, currently I define `fname` (see @ckruse's answer) like functions in every file I need it. **It works but it is not elegant.** Perhaps someone will have a better solution than mine on this. If so, please let me know.:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always refer to the directory of the current file by `File.dirname(__FILE__)` and then use relative pathes, e.g.:

```
fname = File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/templates/some_template.rb"
File.read(fname)
```

**Edit:** To shortcut this just write a method:

```
def fname(file)
  File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../til/../project/../root/../" + file
end
```

**Edit 3:** You also could use caller to always refer to the directory of the calling file:

```
def fname(file)
  path, _ = caller.first.split(':', 2)
  File.dirname(path) + "/" + file
end
```

Comment: Thank you @ckruse. I know I can do that, but I'm not sure if it is a good practice since every time when I need to load a file I have to write `File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/templates/xxxx.xxx"`. Seems a little verbose.

Comment: This is what encapsulation is for ;-) write a function returning the right path. I edit a solution for that.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion where or how to place this kind of methods? I think this method will be used both in the production codes and test codes.

Comment: @YuanhangGuo Ahh! Bullshit. It doesn't matter, I was with my mind at another question. Sorry, just ignore the above comment. I would add such a method in a helper module.

Comment: Since `__FILE__` only returns the path of the file it is written, currently I def fname like functions in every file I need it. It works but not elegant. Perhaps someone will have a better solution than mine on this. If so, please let me know.:)

Comment: I unaccepted your answer to see if there would be other solutions. I'll accept it if there is no better one. Anyway, thanks for the help :)

Comment: The easiest solution is to simply refer to the project root in the `fname` method and then give the path relative to the project root (as edited).

Comment: You also could use `caller`, see Edit 3.